# C# How to iterate through a list of files without using Directory.GetFiles() method

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration

I have several security cameras that upload pictures to my ftp server. Some of these cams conveniently create subfolders at the start of a new day in the format "yyyymmdd". This is great and makes it easy to maintain/delete older pictures by a particular day. Other cams aren't so nice and just dump pictures in a giant folder, making deletion difficult.

So I am writing a C# windows form program to go to a specific folder (source folder) using FolderBrowserDialog and I name a target folder also using FBD. I was using the standard process to iterate through a file list using a string array filled via Directory.GetFiles() method. I use the file's Creation Date to create a subfolder if it doesn't exist. In either case I move the file to that date based subfolder. It works great while testing with small numbers of files.

Now I'm ready to test against real data and I'm concerned that with some folders having thousands of files, I'm going to have many issues with memory and other problems. How well can a string array handle such huge volumes of data? Note one folder has over 28,000 pictures. Can a string array handle such a large number of FileInfo objects?

My question then is how can I iterate through a list of files in a given folder without having to use a string array and Directory.GetFiles() method?  I'm open to any thoughts though I do want to use c# in a windows form environment. I have an added feature that lets me delete pictures older than a given date instead of moving them.

Many thanks!

Comment: Use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` in a for each loop. It's evaluated lazily, not all at once. No storing all the strings in an array and you get `FileInfo` objects instead which have properties like `Name` and `CreationTime` and method such as `MoveTo()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think you should create an array of strings in a console app of various sizes to see how well your computer handles. 28,000 strings in an array shouldn't be hard to handle.

Comment: assuming a maximum path length of 1024 characters, your array would be, at most, ~28MB.  If you don't have 28MB of free ram you have problems code isn't going to solve.

Comment: The problem with GetFiles is that it has to process every file in the folder first, before you can start processing the results. In my experience the more entries that have to be loaded at once the slower the file system is. I'm sure behind the scenes they both do a FindFirstFile/FindNextFile but switching to EnumerateFiles for larger directories has always sped up overall processing in my experience. However there's never been a memory issue though. Like Sam says, it's not a lot of data.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone! This gives me much to ponder. I should not have a problem with memory as the laptop has 16GB. I was afraid c# would not handle it. I will give both thoughts a try and see how that impacts performance. Again thank you from an old Cobol/Assembler/Fortran programmer! How far we have come!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be just fine with thousands of file names. You might have a problem with millions, but thousands isn't a big deal for C#. You may have a performance issue just because of how NTFS works, but if so there's nothing you can do about that in C#; it's a problem inherent in the file system.

However, if you really want to pick at this, you can do a little better by using `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()`. This method has two benefits over `GetFiles()`:

1. It loads the file name and creation date in one disk access, instead of two.
2. It allows you to work with an IEnumerable instead of an array, such that you only need memory for one file record at a time.

Comment: Update: I used the second method and it works great! Many thanks!